# Provide third party class instance using Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I'm using Googles mlkit to scan barcodes. I've included some of their sample files. I would like to inject [BarcodeScannerProcessor](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/master/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/kotlin/barcodescanner/BarcodeScannerProcessor.kt)  below using Hilt, rather than creating an inline instance.

I've tried flagging it as `@ActivityScoped` and injecting `@ActivityContext context: Context` in its constructor, which as far as I know should be eqvivalent to the inline instance below. However, when I do that and supply it to the activity below, I just get a black scanner window. How can I provide `BarcodeScannerProcessor` using Hilt?

```
class ScannerActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vision_live_preview)
    
    // some rows omitted for brevity
    val processor = BarcodeScannerProcessor(this)
    cameraSource!!.setMachineLearningFrameProcessor(processor)
  }
}
```

My attempt to modify the BarcodeScannerProcessor:

```
@ActivityScoped
class BarcodeScannerProcessor @Inject constructor(@ActivityContext context: Context) 
                                         : VisionProcessorBase<List<Barcode>>(context) {
//....
```

Injected into the ScannerActivity using:

```
@Inject lateinit var barcodeScannerProcessor: BarcodeScannerProcessor
```

Comment: Couldn't you provide the class withing a module with `@Provides`? Or do I misunderstand the question? Also, could you add your approach?

Comment: @Andrew You mean wrapping the creation in another module that provides the BarcodeScannerProcessor instance using `@Provides`? Thought about that too but it feels like an uneccesary extra step when I have control over the class? I've updated the question with my attempt

Comment: No you did it right, but I think `processor = BarcodeScannerProcessor(this)` is not right. You already injected your barcodeScannerProcessor inside your activty. Just call `cameraSource!!.setMachineLearningFrameProcessor(barcodeScannerProcessor)`

Comment: @Andrew Yeah I did, and that's when I get a black scanner window. The top snippet is the only way I got it working, sorry if that's unclear.

Comment: I think it has something to do with `@ActivityScoped`. What happens, when you remove it?

Comment: @Andrew Same behaviour. As far as I can tell, scoping it to the activity makes sense in this case.